# How do I insert innerText of elements held within a page on a form held within a modal?

Tags: javascript, forms, events, addeventlistener, hubspot

I'm trying to achieve what seemed like a straightforward task. However, my lack of knowledge concerning load events is making this more difficult than expected. Hoping one of you intelligent people can help me out:

https://rauantiques.com/collections/antiques/products/silver-gilt-exhibition-tea-table-by-maison-aucoc?variant=34759888961671

I want to grab values on the page above and insert it into a form held within the "request more info" button. Below is the script I thought might help me achieve this:

```
<script>    
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        let itemNumber = document.getElementsByClassName("text-slate")[0].children[0].innerText
        let price = document.getElementsByClassName("actual-price")[0].innerText
        let itemFormField = document.querySelector("input[name='customerinterests']")
        let priceFormField = document.querySelector("input[name='asking_price']")
        itemFormField.value = itemNumber
        priceFormField.value = price
    });
</script>
```

It seems as though the window load is not a sufficient event listener to use to pick up on the form fields. I was under the impression that even though the form wasn't actually visible on the page, I'd still have access to it given that it's held within the HTML body (is this incorrect?).

As a result, the script is not accurately picking up on the form fields. Therefore those values don't get sent along with the submission. Using the chrome developer tools, I noticed that when I had the actual form brought up in the console and I clicked on the elements I wanted to target on the form, only then did my querySelectors work, which I find strange. But then, when I'd try to target the elements I want inserted into those fields...they started to return null! So when form is brought up - I can't target elements on the page I want to insert on the form. When form is not brought up, I can't target the input elements I want to use as values on the form.

A big issue here is that I don't have access to the source code, therefore I can't test is as I would like to. All of this testing is being done through developer tools. It's on a Shopify page.

If anyone knows of a way to accomplish what I'm trying to, I'd really, really appreciate it. I also understand that my wording may be wildly unclear, so I'm more than willing to offer as much clarification as I can.

Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, that form is being loaded into the modal through an iframe, which (if you do not have access to the actual code on the actual domain the iframe is coming from) you cannot affect the contents of from outside the iframe

Comment: @Kinglish - thank you for the response! Would you mind expanding on your comment a bit? I can pass on the appropriate information for those that do have access to the actual code on the domain. Is it a matter of incorrect placement of the script? I basically passed my script on to the Shopify devs that manage the page, so I do have the ability to converse with them if there's a way you can think of to get this to work.

Comment: I take that all back. On closer inspection, I see that you're actually setting the values through the URL that gets called into the iframe. Use Chrome and inspect your form. You'll find the asking_price field being inserted like this <input type="hidden" name="48092_198254pi_48092_198254" id="48092_198254pi_48092_198254" value="985,000">. Is your issue that those values are not submitting?

Comment: @Kinglish I'm not seeing any inputs like the one you just mentioned. did a command+f and a querySelector by name and nothing popped up. My issue is that the values aren't being populated at all (as far as I can tell) and as a result, they're not being submitted along with the form. I'm going to keep looking to see if I can find an element similar to what you just posted. Because that would at least be somewhat in the right direction.

Comment: the values are being passed in through the iframe url, ie: https://go.rauantiques.com/l/48092/2016-12-21/4lc9xw?Asking_Price=985,000&I_am_Interested_in=30-9238 - the fields look like this `<p class="form-field  Asking_Price pd-hidden  hidden   "><input type="hidden" name="48092_198254pi_48092_198254" id="48092_198254pi_48092_198254" value="985,000"></p>`